# Why ggplot2 sees 2 binary variables as having different lengths

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using R 3.1.1/ RRO 8 in XUbuntu Linux 14.04

I've been practising making graphs with R and I've run into this problem.  I first create a subset from a larger dataset using:

```
df <- ddply(original.data, c("x2", "x1"), summarize, x3=mean(y3))
```

and it creates this.

```
df #dataframe
x1          x2      x3
0           0       3.837238
0           1       3.083567
1           0       5.084249
1           1       3.727395

str(df)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
$ x1  : num  0 0 1 1
$ x2  : int  0 1 0 1
$ x3  : num  3.84 3.08 5.08 3.73
```

I try to do a bar graph using an example for the R Graphics Cookbook (bottom of pg 22)

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x1, y=x3, colour=x2)) + geom_bar(position='dodge')
```

I receive this error.

```
Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:x1, x2
```

I changed x1 and x2 to character variables to see what happens, and I get the same error.

I have been able to create charts using other variables with y3/x3 but these are not working and I don't understand what the problem could be.  From what I can see x1 and x2 are the same length (assuming its referring to variables length).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three problems with your question:

1. What version of `ggplot2` are you using? I don't get the same error, so first update `ggplot2` to the latest version.
2. Your data doesn't match the book's example. In particular, you have numerics instead of characters/factors.
3. What do you expect to happen?

Anyway, your problem has to do with data types. `ggplot2` is very picky (for good reason) about types. The type of your data affects the graph. Compare the following two graphs:

```
library(ggplot2)
dd1 = data.frame(x1 = factor(c(0, 0, 1, 1)), x2 = factor(0:1), x3 = runif(4))
dd2 = data.frame(x1 = factor(c(0, 0, 1, 1)), x2 = 0:1, x3 = runif(4))


ggplot(dd1, aes(x=x1, y=x3, fill=x2)) + 
            geom_bar(position='dodge', stat="identity")
ggplot(dd2, aes(x=x1, y=x3, fill=x2)) + 
            geom_bar(position='dodge', stat="identity")
```